# NSOutlineView badges in NSSplitView

Tags: cocoa, resize, nsoutlineview, nssplitview, custom-draw

I have an NSOutlineView which I draw badge numbers to the right side of cells using drawAtPoint:, NSAttributedString, and of course NSBezierPath. My problem exists when resizing of the outline view occurs when within a subview of an NSSplitView. The badges move along with the resize to the left or right. When they get to the text of the cells themselves they do not stop or truncate the text under them. It just flies right over.

Is there a way to have the cell recognize the custom drawn view next to it and truncate text accordingly? I have tried the solution PXSourceList already, but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

"PXSourceList solution" working good. You subclass `NSOutlineView` and overload `frameOfCellAtColumn` for this particular task. At this function you need to decrease width of `cellFrame`, returned from `super` call, by the width of your badge plus padding.